# Office-js: Best practices for updating Add-ins in the Office Store

Tags: office365, office-js

Our developers created an Office store app (in this scenario, Outlook app). Every time they made even a small change to the add-in, then we need to resubmit to the store for certification, approval.

- Is this necessary?
- Even if we just make small changes (say, a typo) if we can just make that change to the app (as we host it on our servers) or if we are required to resubmit for any change?
- What are the rules or protocol we should follow in for when to resubmit the add-in?

Any pointers would be of help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Office Add-in is comprised of just two things:

1. A "normal" website, made special only by the fact that it includes the `Office.js` library
2. A manifest file, for the Store's (or SharePoint or Exchange Catalog's) consumption.

As far as the website (#1) goes, you can updated it as often as you want.  It is *just a website*.  Publish to it daily, or even automatically push to it from a git repo.  It's your site.

As far as the manifest (#2) goes, that you do have to process through the Store. But changes here are generally few and far-between.  E.g., you should only be touching the manifest to change fairly basic things, like name, url, and so forth. In the case of Add-in commands (Ribbon UI), you'll also be touching the manifest if you're adding new buttons or changing texts/icons... but even so, the churn here should be *far* less than on the site portion.

Comment: Hi Michael, since your answer is from 2016, could you please confirm that the information is still relevant and accurate?

Comment: Yep, still accurate.