# Update approval procedure for Office-js addins in AppSource

Tags: office365, office-js, office-store, appsource

I understand the general principle to updating office-js add-ins on AppSource as detailed in this answer:  [Office-js: Best practices for updating Add-ins in the Office Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493515/office-js-best-practices-for-updating-add-ins-in-the-office-store/)

What is not particularly clear whether publishers need to go through the whole approvals process every time we make an update to the version of the `manifest.xml` file (e.g. to add new buttons to the ribbon etc) - which normally takes 3-5 working days according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center

Can any users/publishers who use AppSource for office-js addins confirm this is the case, or is there some kind of expedited approvals process for updates?

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested who comes across this, the MS support ticket came back with the answer that yes, *any* change to the `manifest.xml` needs to have the app recertified, which means a 3-5 working day wait.